# Conditional validations based on role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, roles

I have three user types:

```
enum role: { staff: 0, clinician: 1, admin: 2 }
```

Each staff user belongs to a university and selects their university during signup. I want to enforce a model validation that requires a university_id be present for staff users.

In an attempt to achieve this, I have this line in app/models/concerns/staff_user.rb

```
validates :university_id, presence: true, if: staff?
```

here's the whole file:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module StaffUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :patients
    has_many :referral_requests
    validates :university_id, presence: true, if: staff?

  end

  class_methods do
  end
end
```

When I do this, however, I get the following error:

method_missing': undefined methodstaff?' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

Do I need to further specify beyond if: staff? and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: `:staff?` or `staff?`, your question is unclear, but if it's the latter, then that's your problem.

Comment: currently written as "staff?". :staff? references the enum, so that should solve it - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a concern try this:

```
validates : university_id, presence: true, if: lambda { self.role == 'staff' }
```

**EDIT**

actually, better solution from @dukedave:

```
validates :university_id, presence: true, if: :staff?
```

Comment: Thanks Cyzanfar - what is the advantage of doing it this way vs. using a concern?

Comment: Honestly I think that simple validations like this are not good candidates for concerns because of the additional layer. I would go for clarity instead which is simply put in your model.